# Validating password in two different methods

Tags: java, validation, encryption, passwords

I am trying to figure out how to get the program to check the password entered in menu selection 7 to decrypt a file to match the same password entered in menu selection 6. I tried an `if` statement under the decrypt option to check if the password was valid but it wouldn't work correctly.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileManager

{

//store the absolute path of the working dirctory

private String currentWorkingDirectory;

//stores the directory of the active working directory

private File currentWorkingFile;

//used to exit the program, when set to true.

private boolean exit;

// This is a no argument constructor

public FileManager()

{

currentWorkingDirectory = "";

exit = false;

}//FileManager Ends

// This function displays the menu of the program

public void menuSelection()

{

System.out.println("\t\tMAIN MENU");

System.out.println("\t0) Eixt");

System.out.println("\t1) Select Directory");

System.out.println("\t2) List Directory Content (First level)");

System.out.println("\t3) List Directory Content (all level)");

System.out.println("\t4) Delete File");

System.out.println("\t5) Display Files(Hexadecima View");

System.out.println("\t6) Encrypt Files(XOR with password)");

System.out.println("\t7) Decrypt Files(XOR with password)\n\n\n");

}//menuSelection() Ends

//This function is used to exit the program

public void exit()

{

this.exit = true;

}//exit() Ends

//This function provide a means for the user to select an active working directory

private void selectDirectory()

{

//ask user to enter the path of the directory

System.out.print("Enter the absolute path of the directory:\n");

//user Scanner to recieve user's input

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

this.currentWorkingDirectory = scan.next();

//create a new currentWorkingFile object

currentWorkingFile = new File(currentWorkingDirectory);

//check if currentWorkingFile is not a directory and does not exist

//ask the user to enter the currentWorkingFile again

while(!(currentWorkingFile.exists() && currentWorkingFile.isDirectory())){

System.out.print("\n\""+currentWorkingDirectory+ "\"Does not exist:\n");

System.out.print("Enter the absolute path of the directory:\n");

//user Scanner to receive user's input

scan = new Scanner(System.in);

this.currentWorkingDirectory = scan.next();

//create a new currentWorkingFile object

currentWorkingFile = new File(currentWorkingDirectory);

}//while Ends

System.out.println("Your Current Working Directory is: \'"+ currentWorkingDirectory+"\'");

//scan.close();

}//selectDirectory() Ends

// This function list a files level 1 content.

private String[] listFirstLevelFiles()

{

String[] fileList;

int fileIndex = 0;

File nextLevelFile;

//display all the folders and currentWorkingFile in the first level

fileList = currentWorkingFile.list();

System.out.println("List of files in "+ currentWorkingDirectory + "\n");

//use the while loop to list all the immediate

//files and directories

while(fileIndex < fileList.length){

nextLevelFile = new File (currentWorkingFile+"/"+fileList[fileIndex]);

if(nextLevelFile.isDirectory()){

System.out.println((fileIndex+1)+") "+fileList[fileIndex]+" | Dir ");

}//if ends

else{

System.out.println((fileIndex+1)+") "+fileList[fileIndex]);

}

fileIndex++;

}//while Ends

return fileList;

}//listDirectory(boolean) Ends

//This function list a files content, recursively

private void listFilesRecursively(File file)

{

String[] fileList;

int fileIndex = 0;

File nextLevelFile;

//display all the folders and currentWorkingFile in the first level

fileList = file.list();

//use the while loop to list all the immediate

//files and directories

while(fileIndex < fileList.length){

//create a currentWorkingFile object out of each currentWorkingFile in the directory

nextLevelFile = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString()+"/"+fileList[fileIndex]);

//print out this formate if currentWorkingFile is a directory

if(nextLevelFile.isDirectory()){

System.out.println((fileIndex+1)+") "+fileList[fileIndex]+" | Dir |Parent "+ nextLevelFile.getParentFile());

}//if ends

else{

System.out.println((fileIndex+1)+") "+fileList[fileIndex]+" | Dir |Parent "+     nextLevelFile.getParentFile());

}

//check whether the newly created currentWorkingFile object is a Directory

if(nextLevelFile.isDirectory()){

//recursively list the content of the directory

listFilesRecursively(nextLevelFile);

}//if ends

fileIndex++;

}//while Ends

System.out.println("");

}//listDirectory(boolean) Ends

//This function deletes files specified by the user

private void deleteFile()

{

//ask user to enter the input

System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file you want to delete: ");

//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be deleted

String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).next();

//delete the currentWorkingFile

File fileToDelete = new File(currentWorkingFile.getAbsoluteFile()+"/"+fileName);

//ask again for correct file name

if(!fileToDelete.exists()){

System.out.println("***[ERROR: The file you entered does not exist]***");

return;

}//while Ends

//delete the currentWorkingFile

fileToDelete.delete();

System.out.println("You have successfully deleted the following file: \'"+fileName);

}//deleteFile() Ends

private void displayFileInHexFormat() throws IOException

{

//ask user to enter the input

System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file you want to display: ");

//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be deleted

String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).next();

//check to make sure that user's input is valid

BufferedReader bf = null;

//create a currentWorkingFile Object from the choosen currentWorkingFile

File fileToDisplay = new File(currentWorkingFile.getAbsoluteFile()+"/"+fileName);

//ask again for correct file name

if(!fileToDisplay.exists()){

System.out.println("***[ERROR: The file you entered does not exist]***");

}//while Ends

if(currentWorkingFile.isDirectory()){

System.out.println("The file you selected is a Directory \n");

}



try

{

//display the content of the currentWorkingFile

System.out.println("Hexadecimal display of: \'"+fileName+"\'\n");

//EncrypFie the content of the currentWorkingFile

bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToDisplay));

int count= 0;

int charCode;

while(bf.ready())

{

charCode = bf.read();

System.out.print(" "+String.format("%x", charCode));

if(count==30){

System.out.print("\n");

count=0;

}//if Ends

count++;

}//while Ends

bf.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

} catch (IOException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}finally{

bf.close();

}//Try-catch-finally block Ends

}//displayFileInHexFormat() Ends



//This function encrypts files using the XOR scheme

private void encryptFile() throws InputMismatchException, IOException{

String nameOfFile = "";

//ask user to enter the input

System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file you want to Encrypt: ");

//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt

String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).next();

//create a currentWorkingFile Object from the choosen currentWorkingFile

File fileToEncrypt = new File(this.currentWorkingDirectory+"/"+fileName);

//ask again for correct file name

if(!fileToEncrypt.exists()){

System.out.println("***[ERROR: The file you entered does not exist]***");

}//while Ends

//ask user to enter the input

System.out.print("\nEnter Password: ");

//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt

String password = new Scanner(System.in).next();

//use buffered read and writer to read and write to files

BufferedReader bf = null;

BufferedWriter bw = null;

//create a file to store the encryption content

File encryptedFile = new File(this.currentWorkingDirectory+"/"+fileName+"_encrypted.txt");

if(fileToEncrypt.isDirectory())

{

System.out.println("The file you selected is a Directory");

return;

}

try {

//EncrypFie the content of the currentWorkingFile

bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToEncrypt));

bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(encryptedFile));

int passwordIndex = 0;

char charCode;

char encryptChar;

// while loop reads and encrypts all characters of the specified file and the saves the encrypted contented into a new file, and delete the original one

while(bf.ready()){

if(passwordIndex==password.length()){

passwordIndex = 0;

}//if Ends

charCode = (char)bf.read();

encryptChar = (char) (password.charAt(passwordIndex) ^ (char)charCode);

bw.append(encryptChar);

passwordIndex++;

}

bf.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

} catch (IOException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}finally{

bw.flush();

bf.close();

bw.close();

fileToEncrypt.delete();

}//Try-catch-finally-ends

}//encriptFile() ends

//This function is used to decrypt files which have been encrypted by this program



private void decrypteFile() throws IOException{

String pathOfFile;

BufferedReader bf = null;

BufferedWriter bw = null;

//ask user to enter the input

System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file you want to decrypt: ");

//receive the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt

String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).next();

//store the asolute path of the file

pathOfFile = this.currentWorkingDirectory+"/"+fileName;

//create a currentWorkingFile Object from the choosen currentWorkingFile

File fileTDeEncrypt = new File(pathOfFile);

//print error message if file does not exist

if(!fileTDeEncrypt.exists()){

System.out.println("***[ERROR: The file you entered does not exist]***");

return;

}//while Ends

//ask user to enter the input

System.out.print("\nEnter Password: ");

//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt

String password = new Scanner(System.in).next();


//remove the "_encrypted.txt" from the filename

pathOfFile = pathOfFile.replaceAll("(_encrypted.txt)", "");

//create file were the decryted content will be stored.

File encryptedFile = new File(pathOfFile);

try {

//EncrypFie the content of the currentWorkingFile

bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileTDeEncrypt));

bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(encryptedFile));

int passwordIndex = 0;

char charCode;

char encryptChar;

// while loop reads and encrypts all characters of the specified file and the saves the encrypted contented into a new file, and delete the original one

while(bf.ready()){

if(passwordIndex==password.length()){

passwordIndex = 0;

}//if Ends

charCode = (char)bf.read();

encryptChar = (char) (password.charAt(passwordIndex) ^ (char)charCode);

bw.append(encryptChar);

passwordIndex++;

}

bf.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

} catch (IOException ex) {

Logger.getLogger(FileManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}finally{

bw.flush();

bf.close();

bw.close();

fileTDeEncrypt.delete();

}//Try-catch-finally-ends

}//decrypteFile Ends

// This function calls each of the above functions and executes the base on the user's menu   selection

public void runFileManager() throws IOException{

//clear console

clearConsole();

while(exit==false){

//display the menu

menuSelection();

//ask user to make a menu selection

System.out.print("Make a selection from the menu: ");

//store user's input

String menuSelection = new Scanner(System.in).next();

//make sure that user can not use program if current working directory has not been selected

if(this.currentWorkingFile != null || menuSelection.equals("1") || menuSelection.equals("0"))  {

//use the Switch-case conditional to perform the action selected

switch(menuSelection){

case "0":

this.exit();

break;

case "1":

this.selectDirectory();

break;

case "2":

try{

this.listFirstLevelFiles();

}catch(NullPointerException ex){

}

break;

case "3":

try{

this.listFilesRecursively(currentWorkingFile);

}catch(NullPointerException ex){

}

break;

case "4":

try{

this.deleteFile();

}catch (InputMismatchException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {

System.out.println("ERROR: You Entered an Invalid Index. Try again");

this.deleteFile();

}//try-catch ends

break;

case "5":

try {

this.displayFileInHexFormat();

}catch (InputMismatchException | FileNotFoundException| ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {

System.out.println("ERROR: You Entered an Invalid Index. Try again");

this.displayFileInHexFormat();

}//try-catch ends

break;

case "6":

try {

this.encryptFile();

}catch (InputMismatchException| FileNotFoundException| ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {

System.out.println("ERROR: You Entered an Invalid Index. Try again");

this.encryptFile();

}//try-catch ends

break;

case "7":

try {

this.decrypteFile();

}catch (InputMismatchException | FileNotFoundException| ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex ) {

System.out.println("ERROR: You Entered an Invalid Index. Try again");

this.decrypteFile();

}//try-catch ends

break;

default:

System.out.println("***[Error: You made an invalid menu selection]***");

break;

}//Switch-case Ends

if(!menuSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

System.out.print("\n\nPress 'Enter' to countinue");

new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

//clear screen

clearConsole();

}

}//if Ends

else System.out.println("You must choose a current working directory ");

}//while() Ends

System.out.println("Thank You for stopping by. Bye bye");

}//runFileManager() Ends

private void clearConsole(){

String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

try{

if (os.contains("Windows")){

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");

}

else{

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");

}

}catch(IOException ex){

for (int i =0 ; i< 100; i++){

System.out.println("");

}

}

}//clearConsole() Ends

// THIS IS THE MAIN METHOD @param args the command line arguments

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

// TODO code application logic here

//create a FileManager object

FileManager fm = new FileManager();

//clear the console

fm. clearConsole();

//run the application

fm.runFileManager();

}//main Ends

}//File Manager Ends
```

Section of code I am looking at.

```
private void encryptFile() throws InputMismatchException, IOException{
String nameOfFile = "";
//ask user to enter the input
System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file you want to Encrypt: ");
//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt
String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).next();
//create a currentWorkingFile Object from the choosen currentWorkingFile
File fileToEncrypt = new         File(this.currentWorkingDirectory+"/"+fileName);
//ask again for correct file name
if(!fileToEncrypt.exists()){
System.out.println("***[ERROR: The file you entered does not exist]***");
}//while Ends
//ask user to enter the input
System.out.print("\nEnter Password: ");
//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt
String password = new Scanner(System.in).next();
```

Included the part of the method for decrypting

```
private void decrypteFile() throws IOException{
String pathOfFile;
BufferedReader bf = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
//ask user to enter the input
System.out.print("\nEnter the name of the file you want to decrypt: ");
//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt
String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).next();
//store the asolute path of the file
pathOfFile = this.currentWorkingDirectory+"/"+fileName;
//create a currentWorkingFile Object from the choosen currentWorkingFile
File fileTDeEncrypt = new File(pathOfFile);
//print error message if file does not exist
if(!fileTDeEncrypt.exists()){
System.out.println("***[ERROR: The file you entered does not exist]***");
return;
}//while Ends
//ask user to enter the input
System.out.print("\nEnter Password: ");
//recieve the files index from the user, specifying the currentWorkingFile to be Encrypt
String password = new Scanner(System.in).next();
```

Included the part of the method for encrypting

Comment: Could you do us a favor and minimize your posted code to the relevant parts as well as indent it to make it more readable?

Comment: The encryption and decryption works fine. I am unsure what you want to do in your if-statement. Di you want to check if the decryption succeeded? This is impossible without knowing the expected content of the result file.

Comment: I want to add a check to verify the password created to encrypt the file is the same password used to decrypt. right now you can put any password to decrypt and it'll work. the section of code I'm looking at is adjusted in the post.

Comment: What encryption? I just see you use XOR a lot... I can point out things like MAC verification but without any encryption going on, I don't see the point.